# Cyberpower UPS usage with a Linux arm based sytem

Tags: linux, usb, ups

I have a UPS (Cyberpower CP900EPFCLCD) which I would like to connect to an arm based server via USB. Unfortunately, Cyberpower doesn't provide a daemon for arm based platforms at the moment.

Is there any other method I could use to get my arm based server with the UPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used apcupsd for the purpose. The needed configuration for my device in /etc/acpupsd/acpupsd.conf for my UPS are:

```
#UPSCABLE smart
UPSCABLE usb

#UPSCABLE smart
UPSCABLE usb

#UPSTYPE apcsmart
UPSTYPE usb

#DEVICE /dev/ttyS0
DEVICE
```

Answer (score 3):

The Network UPS Tools page quite possibly provides what you are looking for:
http://www.networkupstools.org/

It requires more configuration than the Power Panel software from Cyber Power, however looks like it will work.

I own a model BRG850AVRLCD.

The HCL (Hardware Compatibility List) does not show my UPS as supported, however it IS at least partially compatible, and possibly fully.  The NUT tools I have run so far, do recognize it, and see the correct model number.
They also show it at as OL (online) right now.

After letting it run a few weeks, the software loses connection with the UPS, and started continually sending a message to this effect to the console.
After some web searching, it seems others have seen this also, and that the drivers for at least my Model, if not also the CyberPower brand, are the cause of this problem.

For now at least, I'm going to discontinue trying to get this running reliably on this NAS.
Even though one can acquire the source code for NUT and tweak/compile for their platform, it sounds like getting it to work on my specific architecture is unlikely at this point.